# If input field has value Require another field - PHP

Tags: php, forms, input

**FORM** - http://hoffwebsites.com/CBENT/registration_form.php

I have a form where a parent registers a student.

There is an option to register another child.

What I need to do is if a parent registers another child, and the input field **Student's Full Name** is filled in (name **twosfn**) then **Hebrew Name** is REQUIRED (name **twohn**).

Here is my PHP code in my mailing script.

```
if ($_POST['twosfn']=="TRUE" && $_POST["twohn"] == "") 
{
Print("<style type=\"text/css\">
body { 
font-family: arial;}
input { 
border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
table {font-size: 14px;}</style>
<center><br><br><br><b>Please enter Hebrew Name</b><br><br>
<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" style=\"color: black;\">< Back</a></center>");
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
`if (isset($_POST['twosfn']) && !empty($_POST["twohn"]))`

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not work. It still lets me submit the form if twosfn has been filled in and twohn has NOT been filled in.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['twosfn']) && !empty($_POST["twohn"])) 
{
Print("<style type=\"text/css\">
body { 
font-family: arial;}
input { 
border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
table {font-size: 14px;}</style>
<center><br><br><br><b>Please enter Hebrew Name</b><br><br>
<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" style=\"color: black;\">< Back</a></center>");
exit();
}

Comment: Can you write the HTML elements you want to use?

Comment: Sorry, exactly what HTML elements do you mean? Here is my form http://hoffwebsites.com/CBENT/registration_form.php